# Two Tables, Multiple Fields In Both To Join, Single Output: How?

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I have two tables.  The parent consists of customer data.  The child consists of products purchased.  The problem is I have multiple forms of data that could make these two tables jive but I don't have a conclusive IDer.  Specifically:

Table 1 is `Customer Name, Customer Number, Telephone 1, Telephone 2, Telephone 3, Telephone 4,d Email`

Table 2 is `Telephone 1, Telephone 2, Email, Product`

I need to write a query to meld these two together.  I don't even know how I would do this logically in my head.  My end goal is to match up as many products to as many customers as possible.

I was thinking Table 1 would compare Telephone 1 to Table 2: Telephone 1 first.  If there's a match it would match Customer Number and Product.

```
Then Table 1:Telephone 1 to Table 2:Telephone2.  
Then Table 1:Telephone2 to Table 2:Telephone1.  
Then Table 1:Telephone2 to Table2:Telephone2.  
Then Table1:Telephone3 to Table2:Telephone1. 
Then Table1:Telephone3 to Table1:Telephone2.  
Then Table1:Telephone4 to Table2:Telephone1.
Then Table1:Telephone4 to Table2:Telephone2.
Then Table1:Email to Table2:Email.
```

Obviously, I also want to avoid duplication.  There has to be an easier way than writing 9 separate queries, right?  I'm probably just too noob to figure it out.  If someone could help, that would be awesome.

I'd prefer to do this in Access, if possible, but we could do it in SQL, too.

Please help!  Thanks!

Currently, trying this, and it's returning the right customer IDs set up with products bought.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Customer_ID
FROM customerinfotest T1
INNER JOIN websalestest T2 ON
 T2.Phone IN 
 (T1.Telephone_1,T1.Telephone_2,T1.Telephone_3,T1.Telephone_4)
 OR
 T2.ShippingPhone IN 
 (T1.Telephone_1,T1.Telephone_2,T1.Telephone_3,T1.Telephone_4)
 OR
 T2.Email = T1.Email
```

Now, how do I format my query results so that I get the Customer Info and Sum up their total purchases?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to add a `SUM(purchase amount column)` and a `GROUP BY Customer_ID`. If you add Customer infos in your select, let say : `SELECT DISTINCT Customer_ID, Customer Name, Customer Number, SUM(purchase amount column)`, you need to add them in the `GROUP BY`clause : `GROUP BY Customer_ID, Customer Name, Customer Number`. See https://support.office.com/en-us/article/GROUP-BY-Clause-84eeb766-25d2-4aa1-8eea-002bb65ef3a0

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be a good start. You look if `Telephone 1` in product table is one of the 4 telephone numbers in the customer table or if  `Telephone 2` is one of them. You also check if emails match :

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Customer Name], [Product]
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON 
(
 [T2].[Telephone 1] IN 
     ([T1].[Telephone 1],[T1].[Telephone 2],[T1].[Telephone 3],[T1].[Telephone 4])
 OR
 [T2].[Telephone 2] IN 
     ([T1].[Telephone 1],[T1].[Telephone 2],[T1].[Telephone 3],[T1].[Telephone 4])
 OR
 [T2].[Email] = [T1].[Email]
)
```

Comment: Sorry.  I'm super noob.  Would you mind explaining the difference between an inner and outer join and why it would work here specifically?  Is it really this simple?

Comment: Nevermind.  I wish I hadn't commented on that.  It's like a Venn Diagram.  Thanks!

Comment: Just to answer...`INNER JOIN` will return a joined row from both tables only if a match is found. With `OUTER JOIN`,  it will display row from one of the tabe even if there is no match in the other. The one that will be show depends if you do a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` or a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`

Comment: Thanks!  So, I'll actually want a Left Outer Join if I want to display all customers, even those who haven't made a purchase, right?

Comment: I'm trying this, but I have a bunch of little red X's in my MySQL window and when I try to execute, I get a 1064 error that tells me I have bad syntax and I need to check the manual (which I'm doing).  

I'm adding my code to the original question.

Comment: HAHA.  Nevermind.  I forgot to apply my changes to the test tables.  The query works well to bring up the 5 customer IDs.  Thank you so much!